# FInd content of child of a sibling of an element

Tags: jquery

I need to get the content of the child of a sibling of an element:

i.e. using the id of the input element I need just the text of the button element below, i.e. "All packages"

```
<input type="hidden" value="0" id="packages" name="packages">
<div class="btn-group">
<button data-label="All Packages" data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn dropdown-toggle disabled">All Packages <span class="caret"></span></button>
</div>
```

I've tried the following:

```
var packageBtnFilter = $('#packages').next('div.btn-group').find('.btn').text;
```

but to no avail.

Answer (score 4):

`text` is a function not a property:

```
var packageBtnFilter = $('#packages').next('div.btn-group').find('.btn').text;
//                                                                       ^^^^
```

Should be:

```
var packageBtnFilter = $('#packages').next('div.btn-group').find('.btn').text();
//                                                                       ^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var packageBtnFilter = $('#packages').next('div.btn-group').find('.btn').text()
```